# Passing promises as onFulfilled function in Promise.prototype.then

Tags: javascript, promise

I recently discovered that you can pass a promise, instead of a function as `onFulfilled` function in `promise.then`

For example:

```js
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        resolve("First Promise");
    }, 4000);
});

var q = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Yo");
        resolve("Second Promise");
    }, 8000);
});


p.then(q).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

This will print the following output

```
First Promise (at 4th second)
Yo (at 8th second)
```

This sounded weird to me, because as practise, we only pass functions in `promise.then`, instead of passing a new Promise.

Can someone help me certain use case, where it can be used? And, what is the exact behaviour, if you pass promise inside `promise.then`?

EDIT:

I saw similar behaviour on Spotify Web Player. 
[image]

`this._onStreamerConnect()` returns a Promise, which has `.then` attached on it. `.then` takes a parameter `e` which is also a Promise, as seen from the Watch tab in the right panel

Comment: This is not a "use-case", this is an erroneous usage of .`then()`. It is the same as calling `p.then().then(function(data)...)`

Comment: I have seen multiple websites use the above scenarios. One of the example being Spotify Web Player.

Comment: I highly suspect that whatever code you saw, you misunderstood the type of the parameter passed to `then()` because it does not accomplish anything to pass a promise as a parameter to .`then()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I understood what is the behaviour. Thanks a lot for the quick answer. I have attached a screenshot in the question where it is showing the exact behavior

Comment: Almost all the calls to `_runOnDevice()` pass a bound function to `e`, not a `Promise`. There's only one call I can find on line 4621 of the formatted minified file where it passes `this._streamer.getCurrentState().then(function(t) {
                    return !(t && t.restrictions && t.restrictions.disallow_skipping_next_reasons) || -1 === t.restrictions.disallow_skipping_next_reasons.indexOf("ad_disallow")
                })` to `e` and that very well may be a bug rather than intentional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

> If one or both arguments are omitted or are provided non-functions, then `then` will be missing the handler(s), but will not generate any errors. If the `Promise` that `then` is called on adopts a state (`fulfillment` or `rejection`) for which `then` has no handler, a new `Promise` is created with no additional handlers, simply adopting the final state of the original `Promise` on which `then` was called.

This means that calling `p.then(q).then(function...)` is the same as calling `p.then(function...)`. The `q` parameter is completely ignored and not part of the promise chain.

`q`'s executor function eventually resolves in 8 seconds, independent of `p`, which still resolves in 4 seconds, and nothing consumes the string `"Second Promise"` as you can see from the output.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Patrick Roberts's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53855172/1426891), you can *return a Promise* from `then`, and the `then` function will *wait for the Promise before continuing*. However, to do that, you need to *pass a function to `then` that returns a Promise*.

As such, if your line were to look like this:

```
p.then(() => q).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Or without lambdas:

```
p.then(function() { return q; }).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Then you would see the output:

```
First Promise (at 4th second)
Yo (at 8th second)
Second Promise (at 8th second)
```

---

**EDIT**: To your point about Spotify, *most* calls to the `_runOnDevice` function you're looking at have *explicitly-bound functions* as their second and third arguments.

Most of the argument names are the same (`t`, `e`, `n`) despite their positions, which makes it a bit confusing to follow. I'd guess that these are transpiled `async` functions heavily using lambdas.

As Patrick pointed out in the comments, at least one call to `_runOnDevice` appears to take a Promise as a second parameter. That looks like a bug to me.

[image: Spotify code: vendor.125e9736.js]

Comment: Yep. This is how Promises should behave normally. I was just awestruck about promises being passed as an argument to `.then`

Comment: You say _all_ calls to `_runOnDevice()` but I did find at least one call where the second passed parameter was a promise chain on line 4621 of the formatted source.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Fair cop, but you also see how it doesn't match the rest of the calls to the same method.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear. I don't disagree with your conclusion, I was just pointing out that the example OP provided did have at least some merit that this is something found in the wild. As I said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855031/passing-promises-as-onfulfilled-function-in-promise-prototype-then/53855358?noredirect=1#comment94560470_53855031), it was _probably_ not intentional, and is a result of the perpetual confusion that developers seem to have with asynchronous programming patterns.